# Using a single WITH multiple times in postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

How can I use my first with statement multiple times?
With a code like below I can't use it for any other statement than the one that comes right after it.

```
WITH insertuser AS (

    INSERT INTO 
    zorro.user (username, firstname, lastname,
        accountstatus, roles, creationdatetime)
    VALUES('test', 'test', 'test',
        'test', 'test', current_timestamp)
    RETURNING id
    )

INSERT INTO
zorro.email (address, confirmed, count, user_id)
SELECT 'test', false, 1, id
FROM insertuser;

INSERT INTO
zorro.password (hash, count, user_id)
SELECT 'test', 1, id
FROM insertuser;

INSERT INTO
zorro.phone_number (number, confirmed, count, user_id)
SELECT 'test', false, 1, id
FROM insertuser;

INSERT INTO
zorro.Question (text, answer, count, user_id)
SELECT 'test', 'test', 1, id
FROM insertuser;
```

I get sql error at line 19, near the second "FROM insertuser" in the code.

Comment: whats the error throwing?

Comment: A common table expression is only valid for one query.

Comment: You can save the result to a temporary table and re-use the temporary table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use a series of common table expressions:

```
WITH insertuser AS (
    INSERT INTO zorro.user (username, firstname, lastname, accountstatus, roles, creationdatetime)
        VALUES('test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', current_timestamp)
     RETURNING id
    ),
    em as (
     INSERT INTO zorro.email (address, confirmed, count, user_id)
         SELECT 'test', false, 1, id
         FROM insertuser
     RETURNING *
    ),
    p as (
     INSERT INTO zorro.password (hash, count, user_id)
         SELECT 'test', 1, id
         FROM insertuser
     RETURNING *
    ),
    pn as (
     INSERT INTO zorro.phone_number (number, confirmed, count, user_id)
         SELECT 'test', false, 1, id
         FROM insertuser
     RETURNING *
   )
INSERT INTO zorro.Question (text, answer, count, user_id)
    SELECT 'test', 'test', 1, id
    FROM insertuser;
```

I am not 100% sure if the `RETURNING` clause is needed for the CTEs.

Comment: Thanks. btw the next RETURNING clauses are not needed.

Comment: @user3550283 were you able you get this thing working? I'm still facing issue.

Comment: @GauriShankarBadola . . . You should perhaps ask your own question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Actually I was and then SO suggested me this. I have the very same issue and this thing doesn't work for me. :(